# Too, two, and to

Tags: orthography

Which to/too/two do you use when you are writing, "there are three ways to spell two/too/to in the English language?" My girlfriend has a BS in English and was unable to answer this so I was wondering if you guys had any idea.

Comment: Eh? All three, innit?

Comment: Like that, *(and that's the way it is)*.

Comment: @orbling so you just have to use all three?

Comment: @Kyle: There are four occurrences of the syllable /tuː/ in that sentence, the first one is in standard use and should be *to* - the remaining three are being quoted for the purpose of the sentence, so act as nouns I believe in that sense and thus are spelt in their own ways.

Comment: I wrote saying instead of writing I apologize.. updated my question.

Comment: @Kyle: My answer was with regard to writing.  I used the syllable with pronunciation to indicate that the instances of the same word were not, just instances of the same syllable.

Comment: @Kyle: With your question now being about which thing to write, I'm not sure the question is answerable anymore.  What are you asking?  Don't you have to write all three, i.e. "two/too/to"?

Comment: Exactly @Kosmonaut if you were teaching a class and had to write this (or something similar) on the board which one would you use? Or would you use all three? Or the syllable?

Comment: I guess I should have been more specific.

Comment: @Orbling, isn't there two different pronounciations here?  Do you say "to" exactly the same way as "two"?

Comment: Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: Yes.  Both the US and UK use the same pronunciation for both words, but they use a slightly different pronunciation from each other, officially at any rate. cf. [to](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/to#Pronunciation) vs [two](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/two#Pronunciation)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I wrote "there are three ways to spell *to*", that would be wrong because there is only one way to spell *to*. Likewise, there is only one way to spell *too* and perhaps two ways to spell *two* (the other being *2*).

So, the only way to write that sentence correctly would be to include all three, or write the transcription, [tu].

Comment: That makes four ways…

Comment: @Potatoswatter Vous think so?

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Just depends if the person considers *2* to be "spelling".

Comment: Five ways, then: Phonetic */tu/* is certainly a spelling. Of course, there's really just one way to spell each word.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: That is generally considered to be a phonetic transcription, held in contrast to spelling.

Answer (score 6):

To flesh out Kosmonaut's answer a little bit, it doesn't make sense to include all three spellings and say that there are three ways to spell those three spellings.  Alternative ways to express what you mean include

> The word "to" has two homophones: 
>   "two" and "too".

and

> There are three words that sound like
>   "to".

(If you have an agreed-upon pronunciation notation, like IPA, you could use that.  Presumably that is what Kosmonaut's *[tu]* is.)